# How to handle RSS in IBKR in TWS?

Tags: rss, rss-reader, interactive-brokers, ibrokers, concat-ws

**Hi, this is my first post here, so don't know about any rules here. How to ask, how to tag, etc.
I'm a german stock trader, "fighting" with the TWS daily. Have to learn how to handle API stuff in the future, but actually no time to do so.**

Have still to work with stuff, other peeople created.
Actually using Medved Trader, getting market data subscriptions and quotes from TWS works pretty good.

But I can't stream the news from TWS to that trading tool. There is a connection, but IBKR put some complexity in there. The broker want to sell subscriptions to news feeds inside their platform. It`s in affiliate business, kind of walled garden.

****> TWO questions on that:**

> 1. What do I have to do to "force" TWS, to stream my exitisting news subscriptions in IBKR?
> 2. How can I add my private subcriptions INTO the TWS? Subscriptions fpr Briefings.com and so on.  There is an option for RSS, but I don't
>    know how to handle it. And there is zero How To from IBKR, what an
>    $TAG is, where and how to create a working RSS link.

**The guys from IBKR want to force "dummies" like me to give up at one point in that process. To sell overpriced subscriptions inside their walled garden.
I don't like to give up. So, can anybody help me on these topics? I want to GET OUT news feeds out of TWS. And I want to ADD IN my private subscriptions into the platform, by creating working RSS links.**

Thanks in advance!

[$TAG in IBKR TWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIgIa.jpg)